# How do I dynamically anchor an item at the top or bottom of a list?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-listview, flutter-sliver

[image]

How can we make this kind of list behavior?

As input parameters we have

1. index of the element to be fixed (can be found in advance if necessary)
2. list of items

I can imagine a way to fix the element on top, although the way is depressing:

```dart
final indexPinnedItem = 23;

final listBefore = [...all elements up to 23];
final listAfter = [...all elements after 23];

return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return listBefore; // elements with index from 0 to 22 inclusive
            }),
        ),
        SliverPinnedHeader(
          child: // element with index 23,
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return listAfter; // elements with index from 24 to
            }),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Note that the height of the element can be different. Size of fixed element and element in "free float" are the same (in fact, they are the same widget. I don't need it to start changing size, shape, or anything else as soon as an item becomes fixed).

How can this behavior be achieved?

**Update:**

The whole sacred point is that I want to see the current item selected in the big list, which does not fit completely on the screen.

-> Suppose that our selected item has the sequence number 23. When we go to the screen, we only see items 1 through 4. And therefore, the 23rd element must be secured from below (Fig. 1).

-> Now we scroll down to 23 items and it is automatically detached and visible anywhere in the list (Fig. 2).

-> But as soon as an item is out of view, it's automatically re-locked (at the bottom or top, depending on where we're scrolling at the moment) (Fig. 3, 4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks colleagues, solution found based on suggestions from @AJ- и @magesh magi

[image]

I used the split list to set `SliverPinnedHeader` from the [sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools) package in between. This is how I achieved fixing the element at the top.

To pin the element at the bottom, I used `Column` and visibility state tracking with the [visibility_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector) package.

Thus, the item can be anchored dynamically at the top or bottom, depending on its position in the list and current visibility.

The code for our list looks like this:

(I used hooks to shorten the code and make it easier to understand.)

```dart
class PinnedList extends HookWidget {
  const PinnedList({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(PinnedList);

    // Set the minimum value to see a smooth animation
    VisibilityDetectorController.instance.updateInterval =
        const Duration(milliseconds: 1);

    const pinnedItemIndex = 23;

    final products = List.generate(
        100,
        (index) => ProductItem(
              'Product $index',
              index == pinnedItemIndex ? true : false,
            ));

    final productsBefore = products.sublist(0, pinnedItemIndex);
    final productsAfter = products.sublist(pinnedItemIndex + 1);

    final selectedProduct = products[pinnedItemIndex];

    final animation = useAnimationController(initialValue: 1);

    final selectedItemWidget = VisibilityDetector(
      key: ValueKey(selectedProduct.name),
      onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo info) {
        animation.value = 1 - info.visibleFraction;
      },
      child: Tile(
        product: selectedProduct,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );

    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: CustomScrollView(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            slivers: [
              getSliverList(productsBefore),
              SliverPinnedHeader(child: selectedItemWidget),
              getSliverList(productsAfter),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        BottomTile(
          product: selectedProduct,
          animation: animation,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  SliverList getSliverList(List<ProductItem> items) => SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          childCount: items.length,
          (context, index) {
            return Tile(product: items[index]);
          },
        ),
      );
}
```

A widget to pin at the bottom of the list:

```dart
class BottomTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.product,
    required this.animation,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ProductItem product;
  final AnimationController animation;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRect(
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animation,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            heightFactor: animation.value,
            child: child,
          );
        },
        child: Tile(
          product: product,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the card widget itself (be sure to wrap in `Material`):

```dart
class Tile extends StatelessWidget {
  const Tile({
    Key? key,
    required this.product,
    this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ProductItem product;
  final Color? color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      type: MaterialType.card,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListTile(
          onTap: () {},
          title: Text(product.name),
          selectedTileColor: color,
          leading: Icon(
            Icons.star,
            color: product.isPin ? Colors.yellow : Colors.grey,
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            side: const BorderSide(),
          ),
          selected: product.isPin,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProductItem {
  ProductItem(this.name, this.isPin);
  final String name;
  final bool isPin;
}
```

I purposely changed the color of the widget when it starts attaching to the bottom edge. Just to show the animation, which can be anything.

**Performance:** There is nothing wrong with performance because:

1. we don't rearrange the lists
2. do not rebuild widgets that do not need it
3. not bound to the size of the widget, not dependent on `scrollController` and other things (conditionally, because we use the package *visibility_detector*)

You can run the example and find the full code in the repository here: [github.com/PackRuble/dynamic_pin_list](https://github.com/PackRuble/dynamic_pin_list)

Comment: Really great answer, props to you. Helped me enormously. :)

Answer (score 1):

This may be work around for how you want. u can change to builders.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DynoScroll extends StatefulWidget {
  DynoScroll({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DynoScroll> createState() => _DynoScrollState();
}

class _DynoScrollState extends State<DynoScroll> {
  final ScrollController controller = new ScrollController();
  int itemcount = 100;
  int pinnedIndex = 23;
  bool showPinnedtop = false;
  bool showPinnedbottom = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initScroll();
  }

  void initScroll() {
    controller.addListener(() {
      if ((pinnedIndex+8) * 50  < controller.offset) {
        showPinnedtop = true;
        showPinnedbottom = false;
        setState(() {});       
      } else {
        showPinnedtop = false;
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              if (showPinnedtop)
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        5,
                      ),
                      color: Colors.blue),
                  child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.star,
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                        ),
                        Text("$pinnedIndex"),
                        Text("")
                      ]),
                ),
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: controller,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      for (var i = 0; i < itemcount; i++)
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 50,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                  5,
                                ),
                                color: Colors.blue),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Icon(
                                  pinnedIndex == i
                                      ? Icons.star
                                      : Icons.star_border_outlined,
                                  color: Colors.yellow,
                                ),
                                Text("$i"),
                                Text("")
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I just calculate to show and hide top pinned widget by using height of widget in controller of scroll position. same way u can calculate for bottom.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the offer! In general, the fixed-size idea is clear to me. But, as I wrote **Note that the height of the element can be different.**? What can we do in this case?

Comment: you can try this [scrollable positioned list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list/example)  if we add a listener we can get the position of the widget and also widget can be in different size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited solution after you provided more informations about what you are trying to achieve.

For the `Pinned` tile, I used the same package as you, for simplicity sake, but the `pinned` effect is easily achievable by just wrapping `CustomScrollView` in a `Stack` widget and then playing a bit with a `Positioned` widget to create a top sticky tile.

The logic is to create a `Class`, that has a `isPinned` property, and `mapping` all your `list elements` to such a class.
With this step, you can now track each widget's state.

You'll now create a couple of utility `methods` that will loop over your list, and set / unset the pinned state.

In the following working example, I implemented the `top pinned` and the `bottom pinned` feature, and it works by using a `NotificationListener` and each time you set as pinned an item, it will save the scroll position on the `y` axis, and thanks to that, with the `NotificationListener`, you can determine if the pinned item should be displayed at the top or at the bottom

When you set a widget as `pinned`, it will only get pinned when it's not in the view, to detect the visibility, I'm using a really good and supported package, `visibility_detector`, maintained by the Google team.

[image]

This is the custom `Class` that will be mapped to your list:

```
class TileData {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  bool isPinned;

  TileData({required this.id, required this.title, this.isPinned = false});
}
```

This is your `view`, that displays all the UI:

```
class ListTest2 extends StatefulWidget {
  ListTest2();

  @override
  State<ListTest2> createState() => _ListTest2State();
}

class _ListTest2State extends State<ListTest2> {
  late final List<TileData> listData;
  late ScrollController controller;

  bool isPinnedWidgetTop = true;

  double pinnedScrollingPositionInList = 0;

  int? pinnedWidgetId;
  bool showPinned = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    listData = List.generate(40, (index) => TileData(id: index, title: "Hello $index"));

    controller = ScrollController();

    super.initState();
  }

  void pinItem(int id) {
    listData.forEach((e) {
      e.isPinned = false;

      if (e.id == id) {
        e.isPinned = true;
        pinnedWidgetId = e.id;
      }
    });

    // whenever we pin a new item, we set the `showPinned` to false, to avoid showing in the same frame the newly pinned item, in the pin area
    showPinned = false;

    // whenever we pin an item, we save the controller position, to know where should we pin it
    pinnedScrollingPositionInList = controller.position.pixels;

  }

  void unpin(int id) {
    listData.firstWhereOrNull((e) => e.id == id)?.isPinned = false;
    pinnedWidgetId = null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        NotificationListener<ScrollUpdateNotification>(
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
          if (pinnedWidgetId != null) {
            if (pinnedScrollingPositionInList > controller.position.pixels) {
              if (isPinnedWidgetTop) setState(() => isPinnedWidgetTop = false);
              
            } else if (pinnedScrollingPositionInList < controller.position.pixels) {
              if (!isPinnedWidgetTop) setState(() => isPinnedWidgetTop = true);
            }
          }
          return true;
        },
          child: CustomScrollView(
            controller: controller,
            slivers: [
              if (pinnedWidgetId != null && showPinned && isPinnedWidgetTop)
                SliverPinnedHeader(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: CustomListTile(
                      data: listData[pinnedWidgetId!],
                      isPinnedDisplayed: showPinned,
                      onPressed: () => setState(() {
                        listData[pinnedWidgetId!].isPinned ? unpin(listData[pinnedWidgetId!].id) : pinItem(listData[pinnedWidgetId!].id);
                      }),
                      isPinnedTile: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return VisibilityDetector(
                      key: Key("${listData[index].id}"),
                      onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
                        if (listData[index].isPinned) {
                          if (visibilityInfo.visibleFraction == 0) {
                            setState(() {
                              showPinned = true;
                            });
                          } else if (visibilityInfo.visibleFraction != 0 && showPinned) {
                            setState(() {
                              showPinned = false;
                            });
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      child: CustomListTile(
                        data: listData[index],
                        isPinnedDisplayed: showPinned,
                        onPressed: () => setState(() {
                          listData[index].isPinned ? unpin(listData[index].id) : pinItem(listData[index].id);
                        }),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  childCount: listData.length,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        if (pinnedWidgetId != null && showPinned && !isPinnedWidgetTop)
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: CustomListTile(
                data: listData[pinnedWidgetId!],
                isPinnedDisplayed: showPinned,
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  listData[pinnedWidgetId!].isPinned ? unpin(listData[pinnedWidgetId!].id) : pinItem(listData[pinnedWidgetId!].id);
                }),
                isPinnedTile: true,
              ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and finally this is the `ListTile` custom widget, that I extracted in a separate `class`:

```
class CustomListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final TileData data;
  final void Function()? onPressed;
  final bool isPinnedTile;
  final bool isPinnedDisplayed;

  CustomListTile({required this.data, this.onPressed, this.isPinnedTile = false, required this.isPinnedDisplayed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return !isPinnedTile && data.isPinned && isPinnedDisplayed
        ? const SizedBox(
            height: 1,
          )
        : Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
            child: Container(
              height: 75,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black), color: Colors.white),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(data.title),
                leading: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.star,
                          color: data.isPinned ? Colors.yellow : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        visualDensity: const VisualDensity(horizontal: -4.0, vertical: -4.0),
                        onPressed: onPressed,
                      ),
                      data.isPinned ? const Text("UNPIN") : const Text("Pin")
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

For any question feel free to ask!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I have tested and there are some nuances. How can we automatically detach an item when it comes into view? Now the item continues to be pinned and at the same time it is simply not in the list (which makes sense).

Comment: The meaning of this is reflected in the 2nd picture in the question. The item must somehow detach itself when you reach its position in the list... And again to be fixed automatically when it is not in the 'visible list' area

Comment: I updated the question and added more information about the desired behavior

Comment: @Ruble here you go, I updated my answer and implemented the feature you are looking for. This example only supports pinned items at the top, as the logic to dinamically change the position if far more complex and in case you want to pursue that, it deserves another question, once you firstly did a nice and clean implementation of this example

Comment: @Ruble if you decide on an approach, with for example a simple "pin to top" or bottom only, then we can help you with a more complex feature, like dynamic pinning, but it's hard to help you in detail until that point

Comment: The naive approach, the code I showed in the question, pinned the widget on top perfectly. With (conventionally) animation and no twisting. This is the same behavior I want to achieve with anchoring from below, when the element is not in the line of sight. @magesh magi has provided the behavior of automatically pinning an element at the top, but the method is tied to the exact dimensioning of the element. And still no one has shown how to dynamically pin an element from below if it is not in the field of view

Comment: @Ruble here you go buddy, updated my answer, now it covers completely your use case, allowing to automatically adjust the pinned item location, even if you scroll super fast, let me know if this works for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you are describing is best achieved with a Stack and an Align widget. That is, wrap your ListView (or equivalent widget) in  a Stack, then place a copy of the selected item in an Align and put that Align into the Stack *after* the ListView. Something like this:

```
Stack(
  children: [
        ListView(<your stuff here>),
        Align(
           alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
           child: <selected item>,
        ),
    ],
);
```

The result, if executed properly, should be a an item that is rendered above the list with whatever alignment you prefer. The list will scroll up and down behind the item and the item would always be visible. Make sure to use `shrinkWrap: true` or equivalent because otherwise height will be unbounded.

Align: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html

Stack: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, it cannot solve the problem of DYNAMIC fixation of the element depending on the current visible position in the list.

Comment: I don't understand why not. The child of the Align can be changed dynamically. The Align can be present or absent dynamically. And all of these dynamic changes can be animated.

Comment: We probably don't understand each other. The element should be automatically pinned based on the current scroll position.

Comment: You can accomplish this by using a ScrollController and/or a NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>. But this is something you'll have to build yourself - probably with some permutation of the libraries I mentioned.