# How to fix the position of a widget while scrolling on SingleChildView in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, scrollview, sticky, singlechildscrollview

I have a stateful widget class where I have a SingleChildScrollView which takes Column and a few widgets let's say w1, w2, w3, w4, and w5 all are scrollable what I want to achieve is when the user scrolls up the screen w1, w2, w4, w5 should behave as expected but w3 should stick when it reached to a fix position let say (screen height - 50).

Here is my code I am able to get the position and added a flag too "_isStuck", now I need to stick w3 widget when the flag turns true else it should scroll with the flow when the flag is false.

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
  ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
  bool _isStuck = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
  }

  void _afterLayout(_) {
    _controller.addListener(
      () {
        final RenderBox renderBox =
            _key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
        final Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
        final double startY = offset.dy;

        if (startY <= 120) {
          setState(() {
            _isStuck = true;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _isStuck = false;
          });
        }
        print("Check position:  - $startY - $_isStuck");
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      controller: _controller,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 400,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: const Text('w1'),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 400,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: const Text('w2'),
          ),
          RepaintBoundary(
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.blue.shade400,
              key: _key,
              child: const Text('w3'),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 500,
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: const Text('w4'),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 500,
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: const Text('w5'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: check this out even this question dealing the same. [How do I dynamically anchor an item at the top or bottom of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75791062/14842124)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a `Stack`. Add a `SingleChildScrollView` as the first item in the `Stack`. Next, add a `Positioned` widget with `w3` as its child as the second item in the `Stack`. This `Positioned` widget will only be rendered if `_isStuck` is true.

Inside the `SingleChildScrollView` widget, you will have the `w3` widget as well but it will only be visible if `_isStuck` is false.

Here is the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
  bool _isStuck = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
  }

  void _afterLayout(_) {
    _controller.addListener(
      () {
        final RenderBox renderBox =
            _key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

        final Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
        final double startY = offset.dy;

        setState(() {
          _isStuck = startY <= 120;
        });
        print("Check position:  - $startY - $_isStuck");
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _controller,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 400,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: const Text('w1'),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 400,
                color: Colors.green,
                child: const Text('w2'),
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: !_isStuck,
                maintainAnimation: true,
                maintainState: true,
                maintainSize: true,
                child: _w3(key: _key),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 500,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: const Text('w4'),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 500,
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: const Text('w5'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        if (_isStuck)
          Positioned(
            top: 120,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: _w3(),
          ),
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 120, 0, 0),
          child: Divider(
            color: Colors.purple,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _w3({GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>? key}) {
    return RepaintBoundary(
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.blue.shade400,
        child: const Text('w3'),
        key: key,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I added the key only to the first `w3` because the logic is based on the position of that widget. Also instead of not rendering the `w3` at all, inside the `SingleChildScrollView` we are using `Visibility` widget to avoid the removal of the widget from the tree which causes the `_key.currentContext` to be null.

Finally I changed from

```
_isStuck = startY <= 120;
```

to

```
_isStuck = startY <= -120;
```

to make sure it shows the sticky positioned `w3` when the other one offscreen.

**EDIT 2:** Based on the new information

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but did you run the code? the problem with Positioned widget is once it sticks the w3 widget at 
top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 120),  it is not retaining its old position when you scroll down the screen,


w3 should stick when the flag is true at a certain position and should retain its old position when the flag is false, but it is not working in above code.

Comment: @Adii no I haven't run the code before, check now the edit

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the code still isn't working properly. Currently, when scrolling up, w3 goes to the top and suddenly reappears at its position when it disappears. When scrolling down, it goes back to the top again. This is not the expected behavior. I want w3 to stick at position (screen.width-120) when scrolling up touches the offset, while other widgets behave normally. When scrolling down, w3 should behave normally and scroll down with the other widgets. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Adii sorry, it's confusing, it would help if you could show screenshots of what you expect. I will see if I can help.

Comment: Hi @Almis thanks again, I may not have professional design skills, but I would like to attempt I have updated the query with a screenshot, which might help you to clear my requirement.

Comment: I guess CustomScrollView could work in this scenario right?

Comment: @Adii so what should happen on the second screen when you scroll down a bit more? Will w3 overlap with w4? I mean will w3 cover w4?

Comment: 1st case: When scrolling up, w3 should stick to the purple line while the other widgets, such as w4, w5, etc., continue to scroll up. You can refer to the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd screens for context
                                                                       
2nd case: When scrolling down, w3 should only start scrolling down once it reaches its original position. As a result, w3 may overlap with w4 during the downward scroll.
You can refer to the 4th screen for context.
I guess CustomScrollView could work in this scenario.

Comment: @Adii check now, I think that is what you want or at least close

Comment: Thank you, @Almis for your time and effort, the layout is very similar to what we need. However, there is a slight issue where black/empty space appears when w3 is positioned beneath the purple line and we scroll upwards. Perhaps we should consider adjusting the positioning of w4 and w5 I'll check it thanks.

Comment: By any chance do you have any idea how we can reload SingleChildScrollView? I am from iOS background so don't have much idea about flutter.

Comment: @Adii To force a widget to redraw you simply use the stateful widget and call `setState(() { someThing = false; });`, this recalls the build method by redrawing everything inside!